# Running specific code, while the app is killed or in background state

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase for the push notifications and it works fine. I am also using CallKeep for handling VoIP calls. I want to display an incoming call when the app gets a notification while it is killed or in background (ex. like WhatsApp).

Regarding to the [documenation](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background-application-state) if a message is  received "the device silently starts your application in a background state. At this point, your background handler" code is triggered. But this does not happen. The handler is trigger only if I tap the notification.

I've also added some code in AppDelegate.mm like mentioned in the description but it not works.

BTW: I am currently on iOS and don't know how the effect is on an Android device.

So how can I achieve this, or it is even possible ?

Comment: My use case is also similar. @H.Gndgn
In Android, when app is in killed state, I get callback in backgroundNotificationHandler very late, after 15-20 seconds, but I want it immediately as I also want to show incoming call. I have PN priority set to high as well and that's why we get PN almost immediately in native.

I check react-native-firebase/messaging lib code, their headless task takes time and their react native code itself takes time to get trigger from native side.

Comment: @Virat18 I recently updated to expo v48 (I used managed workflow) and on Android side everything works fine. I also had the same problem as you. Btw: I added the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, maybe this could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution. The problem was that I used firebase console to send a notification which did not contain "ContentAvailable: true" property. When I send a notification using the C# sdk including "ContentAvailable = true" then the background handler is called, even if the app is in background or killed.